How to fix "Error: Cannot find module './cli/validate-engines.js'" after running npm -v after installing Node.js v20.13.1 (LTS)?
After I install Node.js v20.13.1 (LTS) and execute "npm -v" in command prompt, I get the following error. How can I fix?
PS C:\Users\alexc\Repositories\ProjectThree> npm -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './cli/validate-engines.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\alexc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\alexc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alexc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:1:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\alexc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\alexc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.13.1

I uninstalled and reinstalled node.js and restarted my PC. Also, I tried ChatGPT advice and googled, but nothing helped.

Did you find a solution for this?
